# Why isn't syntax highlighting working for Ruby files (.erb) in Chrome Devtools?

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, google-chrome-devtools

According to this press release, Chrome Developer Tools can syntax highlight several languages, including .erb files: https://plus.google.com/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/MnikfMyJ14X

However, .erb syntax highlighting doesn't seem to work for me on neither Chrome Canary or Chrome Stable on my machine (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of Chrome DevTools with .erb file]

There doesn't appear to be anything to configure, so I'm not sure what could be the issue or if there is an issue to resolve.

Can anyone confirm/deny if syntax highlighting works as indicated & expected for any Ruby files in any version of Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: How did you manage to get your app's files inside of dev tools like that? Mine only shows assets and compiled views that are rendered on the page.

Comment: @take Workspaces: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/workspace/setup-workflow

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that it works on my build of Chrome. The version is 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit) and I'm running it on Arch Linux, kernel 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit).

Comment: I can confirm as well; this was an issue for me Jun '14, I'm not sure when but at some point this started working for me. This question should have probably been posted in Google Groups support rather than SO since it was most likely a bug.

Comment: I guess I need to add a time sort when I'm browsing SO... hah.