# Enable Ruby syntax highlighting in chrome devtools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome-devtools, syntax-highlighting

Is there a method for enable ruby syntax highlighting in **.rb** file in chrome devtools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't syntax highlighting working for Ruby files (.erb) in Chrome Devtools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878978/why-isnt-syntax-highlighting-working-for-ruby-files-erb-in-chrome-devtools)

Comment: I want .rb files not .erb

Comment: Same concept for both file types since they are ruby files. So this is a duplicate.